# SAS DDE issues in Windows10. SAS session is freezing

Tags: sas, windows-10

I am running SAS9.4 TS1M3 on Windows10 64-bit.  The below piece of code will cause the SAS session to freeze:

```
filename cmdexcel dde 'excel|system';
%let fid = %sysfunc(fopen(cmdexcel,s));
```

It's a piece of code used to determine if an instance of excel is already running via DDE.  This code used to work on the machine I was previously using (Windows 7, SAS 9.3).

Has anyone had any luck running SAS DDE commands in Windows 10, or is it finally time to bite the bullet and replace all of those reports?

Comment: It's not ideal, but I always just start a new instance of Excel, but that depends on your process of course.

Comment: Does anything DDE work in Windows 10?  Can you open EXCEL and COPY a block of cells and the get DDE triplet from SAS/DM/Solutions/Accessories/DDE triplet pull down menu?

Comment: @data_null_ Yes the DDE DDE triplet option from the menu is working fine.

Comment: @Reeza That's not an option for us as we may have different programs wanting to make DDE calls at the same time.  They will write to whatever Excel window is active, not necessarily the desired window.

Comment: @RobertPenridge and can you read from the triplet?  Show example, i.e. Excel|[Book1]Sheet1!R1C1:R6C5

Comment: @data_null_ Yes.   e.g. `Excel|C:\Users\robert.penridge\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.Outlook\64ZWRZR5\[weekdays_hours_research1.xls (2).xlsx]overall!R47C9:R47C13`